# how to make dropdown or select box in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to make drop down as show in image .I am using ionic framework 
from [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select) I am using dropdown

here is my [code](http://play.ionic.io/app/3e4c1f91d962)

I want to make like that as show given image http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

I want to make only drop down as shown in image (default text in left ) .I want to decrease the width of dropdown in document (as it is taking whole width).Secondly I don't want to display any text from of drop down

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
        <div> View</div>
            <div class="list">

                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        Lightsaber
                    </div>
                    <select>
                        <option selected>Default</option>
                        <option >Green</option>
                        <option>Red</option>
                    </select>
                </label>

            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this by making the label blank and overriding the `select` styles with CSS.

Try something like [this](http://play.ionic.io/app/cbd1b0043d8d).

HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <select>
        <option selected>Default</option>
        <option >Green</option>
        <option>Red</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.item-select {
  width: 75%; /* Or whatever you'd like the width to be */
}

.item-select select {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: there's a "key-board up" class that upsets the UI when it's clicked, do you know how to suppress it?

Comment: This works really well, it's even easy to center the dropdown in your form if you wish so, by using "margin-left: auto" and "margin-right: auto":

    item-select {
        width: 75%; /* Or whatever you'd like the width to be */
        // Center the dropdown:
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

Comment: Is there any way to show ionic drop down as native drop-down?  Just like shown here in first image: http://baymard.com/blog/mobile-dropdown-navigation

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="list">

  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Lightsaber
    </div>
    <select>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option selected>Green</option>
      <option>Red</option>
    </select>
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: this is the best answer because it use ionic clases by default, just copy and paste Lol

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**Template:**

```
  <ion-item class="item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Select Label
    </div>
    <select>
      <option selected>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </ion-item>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-select select,  .item-select select option{
  left: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item-select {
    height: 40px;
}

.item-select select {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <select>
            <option selected>Default</option>
            <option>Green</option>
            <option>Red</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```